# How to ask someone to continue the play when they have stopped playing for some reasons like thinking or looking at their phones?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

Imagine you're playing cards with your friends and there is someone among you who plays really slowly. Suddenly he stops to play and starts thinking about something. How would you ask them to play? What do you say them to invite them to continue the game? I've written my own translation sentences which work in my language. I have no idea if they work in English too. If they don't then please let me know what shall I say them:

> - Play!
> - Continue!
> - Throw your card.

Comment: "Hurry up!", "It's your turn!", "Go!" You could use any one of these by themselves or any or all of them together in any sort of combination. Or as I used to say to my sister, "Go go go go go go go go go go go go go go."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the informality of the situation, there are a multitude of responses that one could give, depending on how friendly you are with the other players, and to what degree you want to show your impatience. For example, a simple

> - c'mon!
> - You're up.
> - Your turn.
> - Throw down a card.

...and so on may be all that's needed to get the game going again. If you wish to show impatience or exasperation at a slow player, then the comments can quickly degenerate from there.

Given the suggestions that you made, they all *work*, but *play!* and *continue!* seem quite formal to me, and out of character with the setting of playing cards.